# Azure API manager using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-api-management, terraform-provider-azure

I am new to Terraform and was wondering if we can use Terraform to implement a kind of disaster recovery for Azure API manager.
I know there is disaster recovery implementation by Microsoft for API manager but I wanted to explore if I can just recreate the whole thing using Terraform.
I am able to recreate the API manager using Terraform with the same configuration/APIs etc.
The only thing which is unclear to me how to back up and recreate the same subscriptions/products in API manager using Terraform.
For example, if someone deletes the API manager, I want to recreate it using Terraform and import all the existing products/subscriptions (keys).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to using ARM Templates, you can use Terraform to deploy Azure APIM as well. You refer the [azurerm provider docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/api_management.html) for more information.

But for all runtime data like users & subscriptions, you will have to consider setting up a backup/restore system utilizing the [built-in feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-disaster-recovery-backup-restore).

After deploying APIM using terraform, you will have to restore the runtime data separately. Also, depending on your Recovery Time Objective, you will have to take frequent backups.

**PS:** Logic Apps are a great way to setup automatic backups. There is an [official sample](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-samples/tree/master/tutorials/automating-apim-backup-restore-with-logic-apps) that you can refer to for this.